# Assigning values to arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to put values into an array, but when I compile the code, it tells me that both arrays have never been assigned to and have their values set to null. Can somebody take a look at the code and tell me what I did wrong?

```
class SinusoidalWaveform
{
    double[] angleArray;
    double[] resultArray;

    public SinusoidalWaveform(double minAngle, double maxAngle, int size)
    {
        int c = 0;

        for(double temp = minAngle; temp <= maxAngle; temp+=maxAngle/(size - 1d))
        {
          this.angleArray[c] = temp;
          this.resultArray[c] = Math.Sin(temp);
          c++;
        }
    }
}
```

The minAngle and maxAngle in radians given by the user, and size is how long we want the array to be, which is also specified by the user.

Comment: Is this C# or C++? They are quite different languages?

Comment: @user1781027 - please post the exact error message(s), and specify whether you're using C# or C++.  But I'm guessing the error is simply that you never allocated your array, e.g. `angleArray = new double[size]` (for C#).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think you know what language it is :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory to both arrays:

```
double[] angleArray = new double[5];
double[] resultArray = new double[5];
```

Do that either in the constructor or on declaration. 5 in this case represents the amount of elements allocated in memory for that array.

```
for(double temp = minAngle; temp <= maxAngle; temp+=maxAngle/(size - 1d))
{
          this.angleArray[c] = temp;
          this.resultArray[c] = Math.Sin(temp);
          c++; 
}
```

That is bad, you are not checking if c++ is greater than the length of the array.
So you have two options. 
Crap option:

```
for(double temp = minAngle; temp <= maxAngle; temp+=maxAngle/(size - 1d))
{
          this.angleArray[c] = temp;
          this.resultArray[c] = Math.Sin(temp);
          if(c+1 > angleArray.Length) break; //exit or risk out of bound exception
          c++; 
}
```

Better option, use a re-sizable array: `List<double>`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't know the array size before running the loop, so most simple solution is to use a generic List then assign the arrays after the loop:

```
List<double> angleList = new List<double>();
List<double> resultList= new List<double>();
for(double temp = minAngle; temp <= maxAngle; temp+=maxAngle/(size - 1d))
{
   angleList.Add(temp);
   resultList.Add(Math.Sin(temp));
}
this.angleArray = angleList.ToArray();
this.resultArray= resultList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Both arrays really haven't been assigned.

Try this:

```
class SinusoidalWaveform
{

    double[] angleArray = new double[MAX_SIZE];
    double[] resultArray  = new double[MAX_SIZE];
    .....
```

Where MAX_SIZE is the size of the array.
If you're not sure what the max size is going to be, think about using a [`List<double>`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the loop, instantiate your array using the size specified by the user as shown below:

```
angleArray = new double[size];
resultArray = new double[size];
```

Arrays are objects in C#. They must be instantiated before being used.

Answer (score 0):

It actually tells you this because you have left your arrays unassigned

```
double[] angleArray;
double[] resultArray;
```

**If you would like to assign values to these TWO arrays, then you may try ONE of the following**

**1||** If you would like to assign the values in ONE step, then you may try this

```
double[] angleArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
double[] resultArray = { 4, 5, 6 };
```

Then, you may access its values using the following code for example

```
int n = 1;
angleArray[n] = 1; //Set (2) to (1)
```

Where **n** is the index of the item in the array. Generally, in arrays, the first items takes the index `0` but not `1`. So, if you say `angleArray[1]` it will output `2`

**2||** If you would like to set the array maximum values to a specific value / assign the values in two step

```
double[] angleArray = new double[3];
double[] resultArrau = new double[3];
```

Although this will assign the values, the values will still be unknown because when you say

```
double[] angleArray = new double[3];
```

you are telling the program that you'd like to assign 3 values but you won't indicate the values right now.

In this case, you may indicate the values using the following code for example

```
double[] angleArray = new double[3];
int o = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < angleArray.Length; i++)
{
     angleArray[i] = o;
     o++;
}
```

This will assign a value of `o` which will be incremented by `1` each `for` loop. As you may notice, I did not say `i < angleArray.Length + 1` because the index in arrays starts with `0` but not `1`

**Important Notice**: If you have an array set of maximum 6 values `double[] _Array = new double[6];`, you may NOT set a value of index `7` (`_Array[7] = 1;`) because you only have `6` indices. Otherwise, you'll get `IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled`

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)